# Which one is ideal for reporting, multidimensional or relational data warehouse?

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, ssas

We are having a transactional database which acts as the operational database for our application. In order to facilitate reports generation, we have been considering creating a separate reporting database. We will be employing ETL procedures to migrate the data from the transactional 
database to reporting database. Now the question we have is which database architecture should we use for the reporting database, Multidimensional database or a relational data warehouse (having transactional database tables denormalized to a certain extent).

I learned that multi dimensional database is ideal for hierarchical analysis of data at multiple level from different perspectives - we wont be doing that.

Our reports are just tabular in nature like typical conventional ones.

In this situation, which one is ideal, multidimensional or relational data warehouse.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Can you give some example reports? Also how much data will you be storing? How big could the data grow?

Comment: Hi, Thanks  Vanlightly. Its a tabular column report for small banking business solutions. The data will be in a range of 1gb to 5gb.

Comment: With that quantity of data you can still be pretty flexible. For any kind of data analysis I think the dimensional model is more powerful so I would recommend that you take a look at least. And it can generates tabular report like anything else. But with 5Gb or less you have some freedom so model without worrying too much about performance. Try a proof of concept dimensional model and see how it goes. At the very least you can add something new to your toolkit that will be valuable in the future.